# Look through multiple tables with a date field and get all that are past a certain date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple tables containing a date field. The tables do not share any other columns in common and I need to count the total number of rows in all tables that are past a certain date.

So for example, if I have two tables like below

Table 1

```
x, x, 2013/8/2
x, x, 2013/8/5
```

Table 2

```
x,x,x,2013/7/3
x,x,x,2013/8/4
```

This query will return 3 if I specify the date `2013/8/1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) from
(
select date dd from t1
union all
select date from t2
)dt
where dd>2013/8/1
```

SQLFiddle to demonstrate:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff17e/1

Answer (score 0):

```
total_cnt Integer;
threshhold_date DateTime;

threshhold_date = '2013-03-01';

total_cnt := (SELECT Count(*) FROM TableA WHERE DateField > threshhold_date)
              +
            (SELECT Count(*) FROM TableB WHERE DateField > threshhold_date)
```